# Date Picker for years only - Oracle Apex v21.1

Tags: oracle, datepicker, oracle-apex

I was looking for a way to configure the Date Picker on Oracle Apex to only allow the users to select years

The default Date Picker looks like this

[image: date picker]

I would like to have something like this, when you click on the year to navigate faster between the dates :

[image: date picker year only]

I tried to switch on/off different settings on the Date Picker but nothing really changes, i always have the full date interface.

Also, my `DATE` column is a `TIMESTAMP` format, is there something to change here aswell ?

PS : I know that I could put a basic `NUMBER(4)` as a column for the date, but I'm not looking for this, I really only want the "year picker" thing.

Thank you in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's actually easy to accomplish - if your Apex version supports it.

I'm on 21.1 at the moment; here's a walkthrough:

- create date picker item
- navigate to its properites
- for "Settings", **disable** "Use defaults" - new properties will appear
- check the following checkboxes

  - month picker
  - year picker
- run the page

When you click the date picker button, calendar will open:

- if you click the month name (at the top line), a new grid will open, showing 12 months in a year - that's what "month picker" does
- if you click year (at the top line), a new grid will open, showing 12 years (that's what "year picker" does

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I already tried this, unfortunatley, this is not what I'm looking for. Clicking on the year only helps me to navigate to the full calendar of the year I'm clicking on. Once I click on the year I want, I still have to select a certain date to create a full DD-MM-YYYY date. I would like to just be able to click on the years, and have this value selected in my field.

Comment: What value do you expect in that column? DATE datatype? Then it'll contain day, month, year, hour, minutes and seconds. If you just select e.g. 2021, it'll be stored as `01.11.2021 00:00:00` (truncated to 1st day of current month at midnight). You can apply format mask (YYYY) to display year only, though. If you want years only (i.e. `2021`) then yes - you'd perhaps rather use NUMBER(4) datatype.

Comment: Yes that's what I did first, only setting the format mask to "YYYY". but the fact that the user still have to select a random DD-MM-YYYY date only to display the year is what annoys me a bit. But I now understand more about the DATE datatype, I think I will have to stuck with it still. Thank you for your time.